# R shinydashboard custom CSS to valueBox

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been trying to change the color of the valueBox to a custom color (beyond those available in validColors) but have been unable to do so. I understand there is a way of using tags to include custom CSS however I haven't been able to put them in the right place.

```
ui<- dashboardPage(   
                dashboardHeader(),  
                 dashboardSidebar(),  
                 dashboardBody(  
                           fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("name")  
                             )))

 server<- function(input, output){  
  output$name<- renderValueBox({ valueBox(  
    ("example"), subtitle = "Subtitle text",color="blue")}  
  )}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hi you can overwrite a CSS class to add a custom color with `tags$style` in the ui like below, modify `background-color` for the box color (here a flashy yellow) and `color` for the text color. Here only box with `color = "yellow"` will be modified since only the class `.small-box.bg-yellow` is updated.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

ui<- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),  
  dashboardSidebar(),  
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(".small-box.bg-yellow { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; color: #000000 !important; }"),
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("name1"), 
      valueBoxOutput("name2")
    )
  )
)

server<- function(input, output){
  output$name1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("example", subtitle = "Subtitle text", color = "yellow")
  })
  output$name2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("example", subtitle = "Subtitle text", color = "blue")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Victorp, just what I was after. Cheers.

Comment: Hi! What happens if I want to make this change inside my script .css? I am trying with this `.small-box.bg-yellow { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; color: #000000 !important; }`but nothing is changing

Comment: Do you have a `valueBox` with `color = "yellow"` ? The `bg-yellow` in the CSS comes from the color argument

Comment: How do you intuitively know what the css tag is?! This is part is so confusing to me.

Comment: @ethan tenison You can find a good tutorial here: https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/beautify-css.html